# How can i check if a String has a specific form?

Tags: java

Hello i am trying to read from a file and check if the form of a line is corect.
Input file:

```
LoopStep(i,0,m-1,1)
LoopStep(j,0,n-1,1)
    If  (ip_fac_p_d_fast[i][j]>fac_tmp)   #Take care: operations are allowed  If(n_32<n_sp_is-c_n_dif_isc_act_pl_down)
        Calc(fac_tmp,ip_fac_p_d_fast[i][j])
    Endif 
Next(j)
LoopStep(j,0,n-1,1)
    Calc(ip_fac_p_d_fast[i][j],fac_tmp)
Next(j)
Calc(fac_tmp,0)
Next(i)
```

I have to check if each of the statements (LoopStep,If) has the coresponding number of paranthesis .

Comment: You can use regex for that. Read this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Comment: Have a look at [regex](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will look it up.

Comment: You might need something more powerful than regex. This looks like some sort of programming language; you should consider obtaining/writing a parser for that language.

Comment: Well i don't have to program it,i just have to read from file and check if it has a specific form, for example if LoopStep starts with "(" and ends with ")"